c++20 syncstream not compiling with clang 19.1.4, unknown type name 'std::osyncstream'
I created a c++ file that includes and uses syncstream and tried to compile it with clang 19.1.4 on ubuntu24.04. For compilation I use bazel with the llvm toolchain. The header is included without an error, but the type std::osyncstream is still unknown.
Here is a full and minimal example to reproduce my problem using bazel: https://pastecode.dev/s/je71yuhm
Edit: I see that bazel is not part of the problem. One can reproduce the error with the following build command (assuming you have clang at this location):
~/LLVM-19.1.4-Linux-X64/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -c sync.cpp -o sync.o


Using -stdlib=libstdc++ fixes the issue.
Using -stdlib=libc++ -fexperimental-library works aswell (Thanks to Ted Lyngmo) so it seems to be experimental

Edit2:

Using -stdlib=libstdc++ has unsynchronized output, it is different everytime. The syncstream seems to be not working anyway.

~/LLVM-19.1.4-Linux-X64/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libstdc++ sync.cpp -o sync && chmod u+x sync
./sync 
Hello, World!
TThread 2!
read 1!
h


Using -stdlib=libc++ -fexperimental-library leads to a free error

~/LLVM-19.1.4-Linux-X64/bin/clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fexperimental-library sync.cpp -o sync && chmod u+x sync
./sync
free(): invalid size
Aborted (core dumped)

Here is the sync.cpp file (that is also included in the link to the minimal example):
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    osyncstream synced_out(std::cout);

    synced_out << "Hello, World!";
    synced_out << endl;

    thread t1([&synced_out] { synced_out << "Thread 1!" << endl; });
    thread t2([&synced_out] { synced_out << "Thread 2!" << endl; });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}

bazel run //:sync
...
sync.cpp:9:3: error: unknown type name 'osyncstream'
    9 |   osyncstream synced_out(std::cout);
      |   ^

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20 it should be supported since Version 18.
I tried different versions of llvm: 19.1.3, 19.1.4, 18.1.7 and it never compiles.
I tried compiling with gcc shipped with ubuntu 24.04 and it at least compiles. The output is however not as expected, the streams are not synced and mixed between the threads.

Seems to compile on godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/95TeqTc45.  [Edit] your question with the exact compilation command that's failing.

You did add -std=c++20 to your compilation flags?

@StephenNewell It doesn't compile with the llvm standard library though (unless one adds -fexperimental-library). It however seems like both libstdc++ and libc++ has some issues with these syncstreams since ThreadSanitizer reports data races when using any of those libraries with the above program.
